# Formatação de entrada

Tags: java

estou resolvendo um trabalho sobre o problema do transporte. Só que todas as minhas entradas são delimitadas por um `ENTER` eu gostaria muinto de

1.ler dois inteiros (separados por espaço)

2.Dar um `ENTER`

3.Ler uma matriz nxm formatada da maneira correta;

Eu também gostaria de Fazer isso sem usar a classe Scanner;

O código abaixo:

```
package problemadotransporte;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ProblemaDoTransporte {
        public static class Cedula{
            int noroesteDaCedula;
            int valorDaCedula;
            boolean boleano;
            public void setValues()
            {
                Scanner entrada;
                entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
                this.noroesteDaCedula=entrada.nextInt();            
            }


        }


        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
         int n,m;
         n=Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
         m=Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
         System.out.printf("%d %d",n,m);
         Cedula[][] tableau = new Cedula[n][m];
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++)for(int j = 0;j<m;j++)tableau[i][j]=new Cedula();
         for(int i=0;i<n;i++){for(int j = 0;j<m;j++)tableau[i][j].setValues(); System.out.print("\n");}

        }

    }
```

A entrada que está fazendo:

```
2
2
2 21 1 
1 1 

1 1 
1 1
```

A entrada que o professor quer:

```
3 3
16 20 200
14 8 160
180 120 0
```

Entendeu?algo do tipo:

```
inteiro inteiro
matriz de inteiroxinteiro
```

OBS: Não soube como atribuir uma tag adequada à essa pergunta, porque removeram a TAG JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

Achei sua pergunta um pouco confusa mas vou tentar te ajudar com a primeira parte, para  "**ler dois inteiros (separados por espaço)**" modifiquei um pouco seu código segue abaixo:

```
BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int n,m;
    String numeros[] = entrada.readLine().split(" ");
    n = new Integer (numeros[0]);
    m = new Integer (numeros[1]);
    System.out.printf("%d %d",n,m);
```

Ao invés de converter direto para **int** como vc fez eu deixei em **String** e fiz um split, ve se ja te ajuda.
Com isso pode pegar dois inteiros separados por espaço.